# Control of Text-to-Speech output audio in Microsoft WebChat

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am using Microsoft WebChat to connect to my Bot Service, and most of the interactions are mainly voice based. I am using Azure Speech Services, and the voice output is completely handled by WebChat. I am currently sending an inactive event to the Bot, which prompts an inactive user if an input was not received after a set duration. This is done based on incoming activity. However, in a voice driven scenario, the event is sent sometimes while the Bot is still speaking a message, because, even though the message has not been voiced out fully, the inactive event is sent, based on when the incoming activity was received. I would like to send the inactive prompt 'n' seconds after each message has been voiced out, but for this, I would need to know the duration of playback of each message. Is there a way by which I can get the duration of the output of each voice message provided by the Text-To-Speech Service, so that I can send the inactive prompt at the correct time?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, with respect to Web Chat, there is no way to capture the speech duration. I would recommend submitting this as a feature request for future development, if it is something you would like to see included. You can do so [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Enhancement%2C+Pending%2C+customer-reported%2C+Bot+Services&template=feature_request.md&title=).

It **is** a feature of cognitive services thru their REST API (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text#response-parameters)), and seemingly, via the SDK (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognitionresult?view=azure-node-latest)). You may be able to integrate speech STT/TTS directly into your project in order to make use of the "duration" property available in the response object.

Hope of help!